# js how to use .reduce() to get an object with arrays out of a nested object with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I am looking for a solution on how to reduce the following object:

```
const myObject = {
  first: 'A',
  second: {
    nestedArr1: ['nestA', 'nestB'],
    nestedArr2: ['nestC', 'nestD'],
  }
}
```

to the expected result:

```
const myObject = {
      first: 'A',
      nestedArr1: ['nestA', 'nestB'],
      nestedArr2: ['nestC', 'nestD'],
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

disclaimer: I was looking for an answer and there are some, but just not using `.reduce()` (or at least I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Since you defined it with `const`, do you want to *mutate* the object?

Comment: I would rather get a new object.

Comment: Well, then `const` (as you have it in your question) is not going to work...

Comment: if I would do it like:
const parsed = results.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return ...
    }, {})
then I think, that it should work

Comment: Yes, because you start with `results` (which must be an array?) and create `parsed`, but in your question you present it as if you start with `myObject` and want to end with `myObject` having a different structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any function for that, just use spread operator:

```js
const myObject = {
  first: 'A',
  second: {
    nestedArr1: ['nestA', 'nestB'],
    nestedArr2: ['nestC', 'nestD'],
  }
}

const {
  second,
  ...newObj
} = {
  ...myObject,
  ...myObject.second
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: ahh ofc, thanks. Why am I making things so overcomplicated?